# one-parameter subgroup of diffeomorphism

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, notation, vector-fields, diffeomorphism

I've got a notation issue here. The question is
Let $A\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ and A generates a one-parameter subgroup $e^{tA}, t\in \mathbb{R}$ in $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$. This one-parameter subgroup induces a one-parameter subgroup of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^N$, where $e^{tA}$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^N$ by $e^{tA}[x]=[e^{tA}x]$. What is $\mathbb{P}^N$ and how is the bracket just above defined?

Comment: When asking about notation, you really ought to mention what sources you're reading that use the notation. This context will sometimes be essential in figuring out what the notation is supposed to mean.  Don't set your readers up to fail by robbing them of important clues.

Comment: it is a homework assignment

Comment: And the person assigning it to you was like "i'm not telling you what it means, go ask math.se?" :)

Comment: maybe he assumed we all know its meaning.

Comment: My point is your first reflex should be to ask that person.  I say this not just because what you're doing is needlessly indirect, but also because avoiding communication with your instructor is an exceedingly bad idea.

Comment: Don't delete your question immediately after receiving an answer. It's unkind
to those who take the time to answer your questions and it makes is appear as
though you are trying to hide something.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written it seems $\mathbb P^N$ must be the real projective space of dimension $N$, which one can think of as the set of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^{N+1}$.

The elements of $\mathbb P^N$ are equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb R^{N+1}\setminus\{0\}$, two elements being equivalent if they generate the same $1$-dimensional subspace.  I would hazard a guess that the brackets mean "equivalence class of" (which is pretty standard.)

Since $e^{tA}$ is a linear transformation, it's going to send the elements in the subspace generated by $x$ collectively into $[e^{tA}x]$, so it makes sense to define the action on $[x]$ the way you wrote.

Comment: And I guess $N=n$